# Indexing my choice field with options a,b,c,d

Tags: html, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to build exam app using django ,i have used the foreign link to connect my choices and question together but I want to add options such as A,B,C in front of my choices please is there any template tags or model field that do such , thanks for helping a newbie

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Django forms library to use radio options. Use this code:

```
from django import forms

FRUIT_CHOICES= [
    ('orange', 'Oranges'),
    ('cantaloupe', 'Cantaloupes'),
    ('mango', 'Mangoes'),
    ('honeydew', 'Honeydews'),
    ]
favorite_fruit= forms.CharField(label='What is your favorite fruit?', widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=FRUIT_CHOICES))
```

Here, replace the names of fruits with whatever you need as options.